# Selectively ignoring framing errors on serial ports

Tags: c++, linux, windows, serial-port

For legacy reasons I need to make my program able to talk to a third-party device for which limited specs are available.  This in itself is not really an issue and I have some code that can talk to it just fine when it ignores all serial errors.

I would like it to not ignore errors, though -- but the problem is that every single message received from the device produces a framing error on the first byte (due to some odd design decision on the part of the manufacturer).

When the device transmits a response, it seems to assert a space on the line for 6 bit times, then a mark for 2 bit times, and then settles into normal framing (1 space start bit, 8 data bits, 2 mark stop bits).  Or to put it another way: the first byte transmitted appears to use 5-bit framing while every subsequent byte uses 8-bit framing; or that first byte is actually a really short break condition.  (Other than this quirk, the message format is fairly well designed and unambiguous.)  I'm assuming that this was intended as some sort of interrupt wake-up signal, though I have no idea why it doesn't use the same framing as the rest of the message, or a genuine longer-than-one-character break condition.

Unsurprisingly, this annoys the OS, generating a framing error when it sees that first "byte".  Currently I'm using a Windows-based program to talk to this device (but may be migrating to Linux later).  On Windows, I'm using overlapped I/O with `ReadFileEx` to read the actual data and `ClearCommError` to detect error conditions.  Unfortunately, this means that I get frame errors reported independently of data -- this is then treated as an error for the entire chunk of data being read (typically 8 bytes at a time, though sometimes more) and I can't really seem to localise it further.

(The framing error does occasionally corrupt the second byte in the incoming message as well, but fortunately that does not cause any problems in interpreting this particular message format.)

I'd like to be able to identify which bytes specifically caused framing errors so that the port-handling code can pass this on to the protocol-handling code, and it can ignore errors that occur outside of the significant parts of the message.  But I don't want to lower performance (which is what I suspect would happen if I tried to read byte-by-byte; and I'm not sure if that would even work anyway).

Is there a good way to do this?  Or would I be better off forgetting the whole idea and just ignoring framing errors entirely?

Comment: Stupid idea... Could you configure the port before the first byte for 5 data bits and after it to 8 data bits? Is there enough time between the first two bytes and between the last and the first?

Comment: No, several bytes are buffered by the driver before it gets anywhere near my code.  As I said the data usually tends to arrive in 8-byte chunks.

Comment: Looks like you either need to tweak the driver (so it can change the data format or handle the errors the way you want) or the hardware. Also, I think, with a small adapter you could receive data over the line input and decode the framing and data bits manually from the audio samples. I know, it's a perverse thing to do.

Comment: I also think it might be much easier and cheaper to get some kind of cheap arduino kit and preprocess the serial data in it, placing the device between the PC and that piece of equipment of yours.

Comment: @Alexey +1 for Arduino mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is a robust solution, but it seems to work for me so far.

I've made it so that when it detects a framing error the next read will just read a single byte, and then the one after that (assuming there aren't still framing errors) will return to reading as much as possible.  This seems to clear it past the error and receive the following bytes without issues.  (At least when those bytes don't have any framing problems themselves.  I'm not sure how to test what it does when they do.)

Comment: Use a second PC for testing purposes, simulate your box.

Comment: Except that you can't convince a PC serial driver to generate traffic that's malformed in this particular way.  Believe me, I've thought about doing that.

Comment: If you showed us the signal as it appears on the wire, it would be more apparent as to what is and is not viable.

Comment: I don't think I can post images here, and I've already described exactly what it looks like in the question.  What more do you want?

Answer (score -1):

I had a maskable framing error about six months ago with teh sue of RTMmouse.
I had fixed it with DOS 7.10 debug,but now I have it again...why?
I had installed WIN95 on my DOS 7.10 primary aprtition and converted all my secondary aprtitions too...with the exception of my boot partition.I reinstalled windows after it was working fine on its aprtition to a win95 primary paritiron.This activated the NMI - to which was maskable to being unmaskable.How do I find the error.It is right on the bootstrap[I have a breakpoint for this with RTM.EXE redirection through the mouse driver after call lockdrv.bat with CSDPMI server provided .

So after intiial boot-i do this right off the bat :

C> debug
-u

I get a bunch of code generated from teh execution of autoexec.bat

naemly tracing the 8 bit operands I cans ee that the CPU is giving the NMI through this mehtod-not sure on the accuracey of this structure from memory but something like an AX calcaulation from lockdrv.bat for every %f in lock %%

then a push AX.Then the CPU does somthing else - it pushes AX and then sets ah to zero

push ax
mov ah,00

this is the bit being disabled-keeping the otehr data bits intact.This is the frame eroor in flat assembly---the al calls are made through si and dx in bx prior to this :

add [si+dx];al

well the computer recognizes modem data bits but I have none to send or recieve[I was up all nite last nite with Ralf Browns interrupt list and debug ] this was real fun.However it is a frame error.I verified the int 14 error with interrupt 0C as a frame error - win95 must have generated it as it does not like my breakpoint [to whcih should not be existant anymore through the v86 but however is generatign an NMI-a frame erro being a minor is still and NMI if teh CPU is notre cognizing it-is one of the basic or simpler NMIs to whcih can incur .NMI means nonmaskable or means no exceptions.An example is a divide overflow to which its absolute answer cannot be devaited with due casue to IRQ conflicts or otehr interrupt conflicts to whcih would form a 16 bit general protection fault0to whcih usually incurs in real mode when two or more programs conflict-or in WIN95 in ral mode trying to use DOS GUI for multitask-as WIN 95 does not support DOSes real mode share program for file loacking and file sharing.

Comment: This looks like another question, not an answer; please post it as such.